# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Tags: java

I have downloaded and upgraded to Chromedriver 85 through Webdriver Manager. But eclipse is still going to version 83 .I have put the chromedriver 85 path in enviromental variable path also but nothing works .Eclipse keeps picking 83 version relentlessly. I have used sysytem.setProperty  also nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

In the Environment variable move your path to topmost. Delete any old versions of chrome driver. Remove any 123 number given to chrome driver while downloading because you had other versions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will occur whenever browser version get change. To overcome this issue there is maven dependency we can use that

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
         <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and you need to add the code `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`

it will automatically check your browser version and download the driver accordingly.
for more detail please refer the following link;
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager